# Results relating prime numbers with extremely abundant numbers

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

A positive integer $n$ is extremely abundant if either $n=10080$, or $n>10080$ and

$$σ(n)/(n×log(log (n)))>σ(m)/(m×log(log (m)))$$

for all  $10080≤m<n$. Here $σ(n)$ is the sum-of-divisors function and $log$ is the natural logarithm.

My **question** is: About any known result relating prime numbers with extremely abundant numbers.

Comment: Why $10080$? Anyway, these numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A217867 where there are some links to the literature. Maybe you'll find something useful there, and then you can report back to us!

Comment: @GerryMyerson: But the only link is related to RH.

Comment: No, Germany, the link in Carlo's answer is also at that oeis page.

Comment: More recent question by same user on extremely abundant numbers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347446/show-that-there-exist-infinitely-many-non-extremely-abundant-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL17/Nazar/nazar4.pdf) lists several statements relating extremely abundant numbers and prime numbers, for example:

- There is an infinite number of primes which cannot be the largest
  prime factor of any extremely abundant number.
- The largest prime factor $p(n)$ of any extremely abundant number $n$
  satisfies $p(n)<\log n$.
- If $m\leq n$ then $p(m)\leq p(n)$.